# Rmarkdown doesn't display dots in formulae (pdf output)

Tags: r, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm trying recent 1.0 version of RStudio, I generated a document that previously worked ok, but now I' having problems with dots in formulae when compiling to pdf_output.
For example when i write:

```
$A(L) = 1 - 1.6  L  + 0.96 L^2  -  0.256 L^3$
```

i get in pdf:

[image: this]

I´ve searched in the web and found nothing useful. Thanks in advance for your help.

It worked quiting the spanish language option (lang: es) from the YAML. Also the acepted answer solved the problem without need of changing the language.

Comment: One detail that i forgot to mention is that im using spanish language (that previously didn't cause problems)

Comment: it worked quiting the spanis language option (lang: es) from the YAML...i wonder if there is a way of avoid of solving that problem without disable spanish language

Comment: You should edit in the question those informations about the language, as they are very relevant to your problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`babel` expects commas as decimal separators when using spanish. Thus, this would work out of the box (and this would be in my opinion the proper solution).

```
$A(L) = 1 - 1,6  L  + 0,96 L^2  -  0,256 L^3$
```

However, you can still get your example to work. According to [this tex.SE answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82013/56508), you can force babel to use dots as decimal separator by setting the language this way (notice there is no `lang` option):

```
---
title: "Test"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
- \usepackage[spanish,es-nodecimaldot]{babel}
---
```